# Timezone php and angular format datetime

Tags: php, angular, angular7

from php I write like this :

```
$date = new \DateTime('2019-11-15 23:00:00', new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$result = [
   'id'                    => $auction->getId(),
   'endDate'               => $date,
];
```

Now in the api I saw :

```
endDate : 2019-11-15T23:00:00+00:00
```

In my linux vps when I wrote date I get :

```
Fri Nov 15 20:27:50 UTC 2019
```

The problem is that on front I have a countdown, and on every endDate is adding 2 hours and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Your front will diplay the date in **YOUR** time zone.

In you database or backend, the date is stored with the default time zone.

Here is an example:

```js
const date = '2019-11-15T23:00:00+00:00'

diffWithYourTimeZone = new Date(date).getTimezoneOffset();

console.log(diffWithYourTimeZone)

// You will probably see 120(min) or -120(min)
```

If you do `console.log(new Date())` in your navigator, you will have something like this `xxx xxx xx 2019 HH:MM:MiMi GMT+0200 (...)` it means that you are in the zone +2H from GMT(*Greenwich Mean Time*). When you store data in your backend, it's always as GMT + 0. But for your user in the front, you want to dsplay their date and time. This is why your navigator convert your date in GMT + 0 in the time in GMT + 2.

Comment: sorry but don't understand very well. All the work should be done on angular side ?

Comment: Which work ? I have edited my answer. Keep in mind that `2019-11-15T23:00:00+00:00` is the time in GMT + 0 (see the + 00:00).

Comment: Thank you very much for message, so how I can remove those 2 hours difference ?

Comment: Why do you want to remove them ? If it's for display purpose, with angular and the pipe `| date` it's auto for you. There is no difference between `2019-11-15T21:00:00+00:00` and `2019-11-15T23:00:00+02:00`

Comment: Remove because now my local time is : 23:00, endDate is : 23:30. In my fron app I have a countdown that display me 2h : 30min. But I want to display only 30min

Comment: No difference but I saw in the api the time is : 2019-11-15T23:00:00+00:00, whitout +2:00

Comment: `const d = new Date(); yourTimeMinusTheDiff = d.setHours(d.getHours() - d.getTimezoneOffset()/60)`

Comment: The idea is that I calculate the difference between : now() and endDate that I receive from back. And this difference is bigger + 2 h

Comment: With `yourTimeMinusTheDiff` from the previous message, you have your desired time